# Align multi-lines in equation environment

Tags: equations, align

I want to write an equation exactly the same as follows:
[image]

I have tried:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \text{find      } &x                                        \\
    \text{minimising} &f(x)                                     \\
    \text{subject to} &g_{i}(x)  \leq 0 \quad (i = 1,2,...,k)   \\                       
                      &x_{a}^{-} \leq x_{a} \leq x_{a}^{+} \quad (a = 1,2,...,n)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

But this yielded:
[image]

How to correct my code?

Comment: When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: just use an `alignedat` environment instead of an `aligned` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "alignedat" env.
\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{31} % just for this example
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
    &\text{find }      &&      \mathbf{x}     \\
    &\text{minimising} &\quad& f(\mathbf{x})  \\
    &\text{subject to} &&      g_{i}(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0  && (i = 1,2,\dots,k)   \\                       
    &                  &&      x_{a}^{-} \leq x_{a} \leq x_{a}^{+} &\quad& (a = 1,2,\dots,n)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One question: How to decide when to use `&&` and when to use `&\quad&`?

Comment: @hmhuang - Technically, you *could* write `&\quad&` everywhere. However, it's no different than using `&&` everywhere *exept* in the rows with the smallest natural gap -- row 2 for the first gap, and row 4 for the second gap -- where you'd need `&\quad&`.